# Why is a page number lower if I specify a color on it?

Tags: color, page-numbering, fancyhdr

In this MWE, if I replace the fancyfoot line with the next one (with color{black}), the page number goes lower (and is even cut).

Why is there a difference between the two versions?
I would expect them to do produce the same thing: a black page number at the exact same place.

By the way, I put a "\setlength{\footskip}{50pt}" because I had a warning with the first version (the color-free one). Maybe it has something to do with the explanation...?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, twoside=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}%
}%
\pagestyle{plain}%
\setlength{\footskip}{50pt}
\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\fontspec{Arial}\fontsize{50pt}{60pt}\selectfont\thepage}%
%\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\fontspec{Arial}{\color{black}{\fontsize{50pt}{60pt}\selectfont\thepage}}}%
some text
\end{document}
```

EDIT:
I'm using the lualatex command (lualatex somefilename.tex) on an Ubuntu 22.04 OS (compilation log: "This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.14.0 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)").
Here are the results:

- without nor color nor textcolor, or with textcolor: same result (page number not cut)
  [image: withoutColor]
- with color: page number cut
  [image: withColor]

Comment: Replace `\color` with `\textcolor`?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the effect you say you're getting -- indeed, the page number is placed in the exact same location. Which TeX distribution do you employ? Do you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? (FWIW, my TeX distribution is MacTeX2022, all updates applied; I get the same (non-)result when compiling your code with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.)

Comment: @Mico I'm using LuaLaTeX, I edited my question. And @egreg indeed, replacing `\color` by `\textcolor` gives the same result (= the page number at the same position) as without `\color`. Why the difference?!

Comment: This has been solved in fancyhdr version 4.0.2. But using `\textcolor` is the best, I think.

Comment: You can also fix the problem my moving `footskip=50pt` into geometry BEFORE loading fancyhdr.   Fancyhdr does not respond well to changes in page geometry.

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce the behavior, but

1. using `\fontspec` is a waste of resources;
2. the definition of the page style is uselessly confusing;
3. the setting of the footskip should be done with `geometry`;
4. `\color{black}{...}` should be `\textcolor{black}{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
  left=2cm,
  right=2cm,
  twoside=true,
  footskip=50pt,%<--- change to suit
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newfontfamily{\arial}{Arial}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\textcolor{black}{\fontsize{50pt}{60pt}\arial\thepage}}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the cleaning and the good advice! `\textcolor` indeed gives me what I want. But why would the resuls of `\textcolor` and `\color` differ on my computer (and not yours)? Could something be broken in my TeX installation? And what is the difference in nature between `\textcolor` and `\color`? (even if `\textcolor`'s purpose is probably obvious, given its name...)

Comment: @Michaël Because `\color{black}` is a declaration: “from now on, print in black”. It doesn't take arguments. Conversely, `\textcolor{black}{text}` is a command: “print ‘text’ in black, otherwise keep the current color”.

Comment: @Michaël It could be difference in TeX live distribution version, the compiler used etc.. For the difference there's already [What is the difference between \textcolor and \color? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86039/what-is-the-difference-between-textcolor-and-color)

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, the different spacing with `\color` comes from the fact that, in the provided example, the `\color` macro is processed while TeX is in (internal) vertical mode. Indeed, if you insert `\ifvmode\ifinner\typeout{We are in internal vertical mode}\fi\fi` right before `\color` in the MWE, TeX will print “We are in internal vertical mode” (tested with LuaTeX).

It is a well-known fact that *whatsits* occurring in vertical mode may affect vertical spacing:

- because they prevent a subsequent `\addvspace` from “seeing” beyond the whatsit (see David Carlisle's example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502458/73317) or imagine an `\addvspace` followed by a whatsit itself followed by a second `\addvspace`);
- because a whatsit at the start of a `\vtop` may modify the `\vtop`'s reference point (according to TeX's rules).

These two possible reasons are given in the footnote on p. 6 of [grfguide.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf); there may be others.

On the contrary, when `xcolor` is loaded, `\textcolor` uses `\leavevmode` to switch to horizontal mode before appending the color whatsit to the current list:

```
\def\textcolor#1#{\@textcolor{#1}}
\def\@textcolor#1#2#3{\protect\leavevmode{\color#1{#2}#3}}
```

Therefore, when `\textcolor` is used (as opposed to `\color`), you are sure that its second mandatory argument will be processed in horizontal mode, and as a consequence shouldn't affect vertical spacing.

As David Carlisle wrote in [the above link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502458/73317):

> The trick is to do colour changes as far as possible in horizontal not vertical mode